# HP Proliant can not reboot on ubuntu 18.04.2 server

Tags: boot, server

I bought a server Proliant ML30 gen9, I tried to install ubuntu 18.04.2 server, but when it finishes the installation, it can not go back on the system it shows me an error of the kind:
The BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU ressources....

I need help please

Comment: This looks like a BIOS / hw problem ... have you asked HP support if there are an updated BIOS? Or, if possible try to change from Legacy to UEFI, or opposite, depending on what you are trying now?

Comment: By default it's UEFI mode but I changed it in legacy, but it still persists.

Comment: Then checkon hpe.com if there are an upgrade to your bios ... find out which BIOS version you have, and what version HPE provides for update.

Answer (score 0):

I found something out on older HP DL360 servers from Gen8 going backwards. The interesting thing is that I've tried this THREE times. This work-around works!

Load Ubuntu 16.04...FIRST.

THEN...do a release upgrade to 18.04.

Again, I've tested this THREE times.  All THREE times were successful.

I have 3 DL360 Gen7, 2 DL360 Gen8, 1 DL320 Gen6, 7 DL320 Gen3.  This solution works on *both* DL360 and DL320 servers.  NOTE: The DL320 Gen3 are OEM'd as Cisco WAVE-574 servers. Simply remove the internal USB, load Ubuntu or CentOS, and...voila! BTW, CentOS 7 does work on all of these versions of DL360s and DL320s.  I've not tried loading CentOS 8 yet...that's next.

Hope this helps...  ;)

-rad